# Ajax return no response when calling another function LARAVEL

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

**Problem solved it was due to the echo in the called function i just removed echo**

My view is calling ajax and i am returning reponse when function ends in my controller.

**View**

```
    $(".btn-submit").click(function(e){
  
        e.preventDefault();
   
        var name = $("input[name=name]").val();
        var password = $("input[name=password]").val();
        var email = $("input[name=email]").val();
   
        $.ajax({
           type:'POST',
           url:"{{ route('ajaxRequest.post') }}",
           data:{name:name, password:password, email:email},
           success:function(data){
              alert(data.success);
           }
        });
  
    });
```

**Controller**

```
public function post()
{
 
   return response()->json(['success'=>'Got Simple Ajax Request.']);
}
```

But when calling a function before the return response the response is not returned

```
public function post()
{
   self::hello();
   return response()->json(['success'=>'Got Simple Ajax Request.']);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO... What the function `hello()` does? If it interrupts the execution or aborts then the execution will never reach the line return response() in controller method post

Comment: @Donkarnash it calls a script to send email and the email is being sent successfully

Comment: Can you post the code of that function in your question

Comment: @Donkarnash I figured out the problem was that i must not write echo in the called function

Comment: Hi, what is the http code returned from server, since you are using AJAX?

Comment: @MohammadFarfour could you please share http code returned from server using https://support.deskpro.com/en/kb/articles/how-to-inspect-ajax-requests-with-chrome-tools?

Comment: Yes, you must not use echo. Everything you need to send to the client should be included in the response because a laravel response (which extends the Symfony response) contains both response headers and body but if you've already echoed something you can't then send headers.